# Usage of erdulden and dulden?

Tags: difference, usage

Erdulden means "to endure" and dulden "to tolerate"
What is the difference in usage and how are they used mainly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl, dr:** The more one suffers and the less one can do about it, the more *erdulden is indicated*. If there is either no or only slight negative impact and the person could stop it without or with only minor consequences *dulden* is the right choice.

Note: This answer is mainly based on my sprachgefühl and the Wiktionary articles on [dulden](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dulden) and [erdulden](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erdulden).

*Dulden* and *erdudeln* are very similiar with only slight differences:

- In both cases the person who "duldet/erduldet" would be able to do something to but chooses not to. Furthermore the person receives no benefit from the thing happening.
- In case of *dulden*:
  The person chooses not to prevent it as they are not or only slightly negatively impacted.
- In case of *erdulden*:
  Even though the person could prevent it, they choose not to as possibly something more negative would happen otherwise.

**Examples:**

- "Er *duldet/erduldet* den Hirten und die Schafe auf seiner Wiese"

  - Motivation: Because it is of no use for him and he doesn't care

    - Only *Dulden* is possible. *Erdulden* is not possible with this motivation, as there is no negativ impact.
- Er *dudelt/erduldet* die unfaire Behandlung durch den Lehrer ohne Widerrede

  - Motivation: Because if he complains nobody would believe him

    - *Erdudeln* is possible, *dudeln* does not fit
  - Motivation: Because he does not care about school

    - More likely to use *dulden*
- Er *dudelt/erdult* das Geschrei der spielenden Kinder.

  - Motivation: He doesn't wanna spoil the fun

    - Both is possible, depending on how much he is affected by the noise. Tendency to *dulden*
  - Motivation: Complaining would result in trouble with the parents.

    - Both is possible. With *dulden* either the disturbance isn't to strong or the trouble is the parents would not be to severe. With *erdulden* both, the disturbance and the trouble with the parents would be more severe.
- Synonyms for dulden: *akzeptieren*
- Synonyms for erdulden: *ertragen*, *aushalten*

Answer (score 4):

"Erdulden" is more like suffering than tolerating.

Comment: Do you mean that erdulden can be used as "tolerate" to talk about sth painful or sth difficult

Comment: Yes I think it would be correct to use it in that way.

Answer (score 2):

*Dulden* implies consent

*Erdulden* is more of unwillingly suffering through something.

Comment: I would question *unwillingly* and the answer is already quite on the short side.